# Loop and StringBuilder

Tags: java, loops, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a guessing game similar to hangman. I have most of the code complete and it compiles fine. However, when I run my code it does not seem to completely run through the program. I am guessing it is something to do with StringBuilder. Any feedback is welcomed. Thank you!

```
import java.lang.String;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class GuessGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String answer = "G1123 I4 L1123!";
String guessAnswer = "Goose Is Loose!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(15);

sb.append("G**** I* L****!");
/*
sb.append("012345678901234");
*/
//create string array and split into
String entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
 //sorting loop method to find if letter exists

for(int i = 0; i < 26;i++){
    if (entry.equals("e")){
    sb.replace(4,5,"e");
    sb.replace(13,14,"e");
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
 //sorting loop method to find if letter exists

    }else if (entry.equals("o")){
    sb.replace(1,3,"oo");
    sb.replace(10,12,"oo");
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
 //sorting loop method to find if letter exists

    }else if(entry.equals("s")){
    sb.replace(3,4,"s");
    sb.replace(12,13,"s");
    sb.replace(7,8,"s");
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
 //sorting loop method to find if letter exists

    }else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect letter guess! Try again. "); 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
 //sorting loop method to find if letter exists

    }
}


if(answer == guessAnswer){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!!! Answer is: " + sb); 
}else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose: Answer is: " + sb); 
} 
}
}
```

//edit after Tom's advice:

```
import java.lang.String;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class GuessGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String answer = "G1123 I4 L1123!";
String guessAnswer = "Goose Is Loose!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(15);

sb.append("G**** I* L****!");
/*
sb.append("012345678901234");
*/
//create string array and split into
String entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
 //sorting loop method to find if letter exists

for(int i = 0; i < 26;i++){
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);

    if (entry.equals("e")){
    sb.replace(4,5,"e");
    sb.replace(13,14,"e");

    }else if (entry.equals("o")){
    sb.replace(1,3,"oo");
    sb.replace(10,12,"oo");


    }else if(entry.equals("s")){
    sb.replace(3,4,"s");
    sb.replace(12,13,"s");
    sb.replace(7,8,"s");


    }else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect letter guess! Try again. "); 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);


    }
}


if (sb.toString().equals(guessAnswer)){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!!! Answer is: " + sb); 
}else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose: Answer is: " + sb); 
} 
}
}
```

//Final Code

```
import java.lang.String;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class GuessGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String answer = "G1123 I4 L1123!";
String guessAnswer = "Goose Is Loose!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(15);

sb.append("G**** I* L****!");
/*
sb.append("012345678901234");
*/
//create string array and split into
String entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
 //sorting loop method to find if letter exists

for(int i = 0; i < 26;i++){
entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
    if(sb.toString().equals(guessAnswer)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!!! Answer is: " + sb); 
    break;

    }else if (entry.equals("e")){
    sb.replace(4,5,"e");
    sb.replace(13,14,"e");

    }else if (entry.equals("o")){
    sb.replace(1,3,"oo");
    sb.replace(10,12,"oo");


    }else if(entry.equals("s")){
    sb.replace(3,4,"s");
    sb.replace(12,13,"s");
    sb.replace(7,8,"s");


    }else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect letter guess! Try again. "); 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);


    }
}
if ((sb.toString().equals(guessAnswer)) == false){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose: Answer is: " + sb);

} 

}
}
```

Comment: please put JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
after the if loop and remove the others, it's driving me nuts.  You only need it once as you show it no matter what they input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need to be changed.

First, as noted already, your ending condition should check `StringBuilder` `sb` value.

```
    if (sb.toString().equals(guessAnswer)) {
```

Also, you need to change what `entry` contains each time you show the `JOptionPane`, like this

```
entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "You have 25 chances to guess the phrase! Guess one letter at a time!\n" + sb);
```

Now, doing that and clicking on `Cancel` will throw a `NullPointerException`, so you need to check if `entry` is `null` to stop.

Checking if someone wins should be done more often so you don't wait the 25 turns to get the "Winning" message. Add a `isWin(sb)` method after someone enters a valid letter would be a good way.

You also forgot, when someone enters `e`, to change the last `e` in `Loose!`.

Comment: In the new version, sometimes it's going to ask the user, ignore them, then ask them again.  Just have a single entry=JOptionPane... at the top of the for loop and you're fine.

Comment: Indeed but doing it once or more doesn't matter, it still needs to be updated :)

Answer (score 0):

you never modify the answer variable

replace

```
if(answer == guessAnswer)
```

with

```
if (sb.toString().equals(guessAnswer))
```

Also, I think it's still not going to work but for other reasons.  Put this at the end to find out why:

```
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I switched it out, yet I am still getting the same issue when I test the program. It runs on letter and will not take any other letter.